# Typescript: access an object property with square bracket notation and variable

Tags: typescript

What is the correct way in TypeScript to access a Javascript object with `[ ]` notation and using a variable (that we are initially unsure of its value) that evaluates to a string with the brackets to access an objects property, i.e. `myObject[myVariable]`

The following code errors as expected as we have an unknown value in `x` so we can not be sure that it is a key of myDictionary (however, this isn't exactly the error, see code comment):

```
const myDictionary = {
  key1: 'String 1',
  key2: 'String 2',
  key3: 'String 3',
};

const possibleValuesOfX = [
  'key1',
  'notAKey1',
  'key2',
  'notAKey2',
  'key3',
  'notAKey3',
];

// simulating a random value that could be a possible key of myDictionary
const x =
  possibleValuesOfX[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleValuesOfX.length)];

// The following errors: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ key1: string; key2: string; key3: string; }'.ts(7053)
const decode = myDictionary[x];
```

So I try the following, thinking I'm checking to ensure `x` is a key of `myDictionary` before attempting to access `myDictionary` with `x`

```
const myDictionary = {
  key1: 'String 1',
  key2: 'String 2',
  key3: 'String 3',
};

const possibleValuesOfX = [
  'key1',
  'notAKey1',
  'key2',
  'notAKey2',
  'key3',
  'notAKey3',
];

const x =
  possibleValuesOfX[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleValuesOfX.length)];

let decode: string;
if (x in myDictionary) {
  // Still produces the same error as above
  decode = myDictionary[x];
}
```

This doesn't stop the error.

Now I can stop the error with `const myDictionary: { [key: string]: string }` but this also stops autocomplete from working with `myDictionary` and provides little else from what I can see.

To keep auto complete and stop the error I can do the following:

```
type myDictionaryKeys = 'key1' | 'key2' | 'key3';
const myDictionary: Record<myDictionaryKeys, string> = {
  key1: 'String 1',
  key2: 'String 2',
  key3: 'String 3',
};

const possibleValuesOfX = [
  'key1',
  'notAKey1',
  'key2',
  'notAKey2',
  'key3',
  'notAKey3',
];

const x =
  possibleValuesOfX[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleValuesOfX.length)];

let decode: string;
if (x in myDictionary) {
  decode = myDictionary[x as myDictionaryKeys];
}
```

But this still feels 'hacky' and overly verbose  as I'm casting `x as myDictionaryKeys` to remove the error and having to type the keys out twice once in `myDictionary` object and once in `myDictionaryKeys` type.

Is there a 'proper' way to do this, or a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: example updated in response to the question in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70740311/typescript-access-an-object-property-with-square-bracket-notation-and-variable/70740495?noredirect=1#comment125062922_70740495).

---

You can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to inform the compiler that the value is a key in the dictionary, like the `isDictionaryKey` function in this example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=29&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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)

```ts
function isDictionaryKey <T>(
  dictionary: T,
  str: string,
): str is keyof Omit<T, number | symbol> {
  return str in myDictionary;
}

const myDictionary = {
  key1: 'String 1',
  key2: 'String 2',
  key3: 'String 3',
};

const possibleValuesOfX = [
  'key1',
  'notAKey1',
  'key2',
  'notAKey2',
  'key3',
  'notAKey3',
];

const x = possibleValuesOfX[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleValuesOfX.length)];

let decode: string;
if (x && isDictionaryKey(myDictionary, x)) {
  x; // "key1" | "key2" | "key3"
  decode = myDictionary[x];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to make `isDictionaryKey()` generic to work with any passed in dictionary or would you have to create one of these functions for each dictionary you want to use it with?

Comment: @DanielGranger See my updated answer.